# Get C# String from "char*" returned from C++ library method?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a C++ library that I use in my C# application. One of the methods in the C++ library returns a `char *`. How can I convert that `char *` into a string in my C# application?

Apparently in my C# application, the data type returned in this method is of type `sbyte *`.

Comment: P/Invoke or...? (Please tag with the approach used for access.)

Comment: Marshal it as `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @pst i am not sure since i am very new to C++ programming.. i have methods in the sources section and the methods that will be used by the c# application in the header section. In the header section there is the method signatures..

Comment: @cicada where will i use that? in the C++ part or the C#?

Comment: Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s9t975.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` has [a constructor that takes a `char*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/6y4za026.aspx):

```
char* x = ...
string s = new string(x);
```

And [another one that takes a `sbyte*`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s9t975):

```
sbyte* x = ...
string s = new string(x);
```

Comment: the following error is being generated when I assign sbyte * x to the C++ method that returns the char * : Error 1 Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context..  Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: found what the problem was... i had to write unsafe in the method signature... :) thanks a lot !:)